# How to properly embed QEventLoop in the std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, concurrency

There is an object that contains `std::thread` that I want to be finished when the object is destroyed.

Minimal working code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <QEventLoop>

struct Connector
{
    Connector(std::string addr, std::function<void(std::string)> cb)
    {
        std::promise<void> barrier;
        auto fut = barrier.get_future();

        m_worker = std::thread([addr, cb, &barrier]()
        {
            QEventLoop loop;
            QTimer::singleShot(0, [this, &barrier, &loop]
            {
                m_quit = [&loop] { QTimer::singleShot(0, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit); };
                barrier.set_value();
            });

            MySocket s(addr, cb);

            loop.exec();
        });

        fut.wait();
    }

    ~Connector()
    {
        m_quit();
        m_worker.join();
    }

    std::thread worker;
    std::function<void()> m_quit;
};
```

It becomes complex very fast: you can call `exit()` on the `loop` only after it enters the `exec()`, you can't create the `loop` outside of the thread.

I only have a solution with a semaphore that is released by a handler that is queued for the execution in this loop. When the semaphore is released I can be sure that the loop is created and running, so it can be terminated with a `quit()` message when needed.

Am I missing a simpler way?

Comment: How do you do anything with `loop`? You can't access it and you can't send events to it.

Comment: @nwp, by creating some objects just before the `exec()`. Something like a socket, pass an IP address to connect and `std::function` callback for data.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you communicate with the event loop via sockets. It looks a bit like you are re-implementing [`QThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html). It already comes with an event loop and signal/slot support.

Comment: @nwp, I don't need `QThread`. The question is about `std::thread`. Added a usage example to the question.

Comment: I don't understand what `MySocket s` is for. It cannot be used by the worker thread because it is stuck in `loop.exec()` and it cannot be used by anyone else because it's a local variable.

Comment: @nwp, it's processed in `loop.exec()` (all its slots, signals, timers, etc.). Are you sure that you've used these Qt classes before?

Comment: I am using `std::thread` and `QEventLoop` extensively. From that statement I can imagine `MySocket` is actually `QTcpSocket` and there is some connecting of slots going on that is not shown. By the way, with `QThread` you could totally create the `loop` outside the thread and then just use [`moveToThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could pass a reference to a unique_ptr of QEventLoop to the thread and at destruction call exit on that pointer. Like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <QEventLoop>

struct Connector
{
    Connector()
    {
        m_worker = std::thread([=]()
        {
            event_loop = std::make_unique<QEventLoop>();
            loop->exec();
        });
    }

    ~Connector()
    {
        event_loop->exit();
        m_worker.join();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<QEventLoop> event_loop;
    std::thread worker;
};
```

Comment: The `~Connector()` may be executed before the `event_loop = std::make_unique<QEventLoop>();`. And it'll crash on the NULL pointer in this case.

Comment: True. You could add a `std::atomic_flag` to the constructor and wait until it is set by the thread after the make_unique call. Then in the destructor you could call `event_loop->isRunning()` to check if it can be exited.

Comment: Then the `event_loop->isRunning()` in `~Connector()` may be executed after the `event_loop = std::make_unique<QEventLoop>();` and the `std::atomic_flag` but before the call to `loop->exec()`. It'll call `event_loop->exit();` without any effect (or you may not even call it if you check `isRunning()`), then the thread will hang in `loop->exec();` while the main thread will lock up in `m_worker.join();`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it, based on katrasnikj's answer and [std::promise docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) to ensure that the thread is running by the time the constructor finishes.

```
struct Connector
{
    Connector()
    {
        std::promise<void> barrier;
        auto fut = barrier.get_future();
        worker = std::thread([=](std::promise<void>&& barrier)
        {
            event_loop = std::make_unique<QEventLoop>();
            barrier.set_value();
            event_loop->exec();
        }, std::move(barrier));
        fut.wait();
    }

    ~Connector()
    {
        QTimer::singleShot(0, event_loop.get(), &QEventLoop::quit);
        worker.join();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<QEventLoop> event_loop;
    std::thread worker;
};
```

But you might want to look into using `QThread` instead, since it's capable of running its own event loop.

Comment: The `barrier.set_value();` is never executed. The `event_loop->exec();` blocks before that. But it's nice that you've mentioned the `std::promise`. I'll use it in my QSemaphore solution instead of the semaphore. I've updated the question.

Comment: There is a problem with calling `QTimer::singleShot()`: an error `Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread`. So can't really start a timer from a non-EventLoop main thread.

Comment: You should be able to use `invokeMethod` instead, in this case. I'll prepare an example in 1-2h.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why it wouldn't work, so that's also an option.